# find the differential dy

Tags: calculus

I know this is right is it not? I did the work and I am almost positive I did it right.

[image]

Comment: you are missing one decimal place: 0.00866

Comment: Then round to 0.009

Comment: thank you @hickslebummbumm I was just missing one zero hah

Answer (score 0):

$$ -\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\cdot (-0.01)= \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\cdot (0.01)=0.008660254 $$
After rounding we have 
$$ 0.009 $$